# Google Analytics campaign tagging JSP pages

Tags: google-analytics

I am trying to tag my website with google analytics which is a JSP page that comes like this http://www.testsite.com/page.jsp?formType=GENERIC#page1.

When I append Google analytics UTM tag at the end, it always strips them off

So
http://www.testsite.com/page.jsp?formType=GENERIC#page1&utm_source=test1&utm_campaign=test2&utm_medium=test3

becomes 
http://www.testsite.com/page.jsp?formType=GENERIC#page1

Btw, this is a mobile website.

How should I properly tag this kind of website.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a solution:

If I put utm tags before the requested page "page1" as in http://www.testsite.com/page.jsp?formType=GENERIC#page1

The URL looks like this and utm tags won't get stripped off and pages still show up correctly:

http://www.testsite.com/page.jsp?formType=GENERIC&utm_source=test1&utm_campaign=test2&utm_medium=test3#page1

Does anybody know how this worked?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the GA parameters need to be part of the Query string, and you are adding them to the hashtag string.

(spaces are because of SO format limitations)

http://www.mysite.com/page.html **?thisisyourquerystring** #thisisyourhashtagstring

Also, the query string should come before the hashtag string.